# Google Apps Script for Approving or Denying Request -

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the script editor within Google Sheets and I am trying to write a script to approve or deny a request. This is not something I have to get done for work, but it is a project that I believe would be great for our environment.

I have attached the code of the google sheets document. I receive two errors and I am very lost right now, this is my first time using the Google Sheets Script Editor. I have done a lot of searching for someone that has the same error as I do, but haven't had much luck.

**Error #1: This comes from the 2nd line of the formSubmitReply Function.**
           TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined (line 2, file"MyFileName")

**Error #2: This comes from the 4th line of the emailStatusUpdates Function.**
           Error: The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid (line 31, file"MyFileName")

```
*function formSubmitReply(e) {
  **var userEmail = e.values[7];**
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue("New");
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
                    "Professional Development Request",
                    "Thanks for submitting your issue. \n\nI will start " +
                    "working on it as soon as possible. \n\nMrs. Frost",
                    {name:"PD Request"});
}​
function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spread.getSheets()[0];
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
function emailStatusUpdates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  **var userEmail = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("contactmail")).getValue();**
  var subject = "Status" + row;
  var body = "Your Flexible Professional Development Day Request has been\n\nStatus: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Status")).getValue();

  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {Name:"Status"});
}
function onOpen() {
  var subMenus = [{name:"Send Status Email", functionName: "emailStatusUpdates"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Professional Development Request Menu", subMenus);
}​
```

Comment: If you are running the code from the code editor, then the event object, that is designated as `e` will not receive anything.  `formSubmitReply(e)`  The only way that `e` can receive a value, is if a Google Form is submitted, and that function is set up as an "On Form Submit" trigger.  The `getColIndexByName` function can return -1 if the column name is not found.  What is it returning?  Use a `Logger.log()` statement to find out.  `if (name == colName) {Logger.log('there was a match')
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }`

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try.

Comment: So I added the Logger API to the getColIndexByName function
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) { Logger.log('there was a match')
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;

                                                                                                   However, I go to look at the logs and it says I haven't used the Logger API, but I know I did.

Comment: I've had it happen to me that it states that there is nothing in the Logs, and I really don't know why.  It's usually something that I did wrong.